# Fermat"s point proof using ceva theorem?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Question -

equilateral triangles DBC, ECA and FAB are constructed externally on the sides BC,CA,AB respectively of triangle ABC. Prove that AD, BE, and CF are also concurrent.

My attempt -

I know this is fermat point and also that this question is already been answered but I am not getting how to proof this using ceva theorem to prove concurrency....I know the proof using rotation... kindly help me thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A'$ be the intersection of $AD$ and $BC$. Then (if all angles are less than $2\pi/3$):

$$\frac{A'B}{A'C} = - \frac{\text{Area}(ABD)}{\text{Area}(ACD)} =  - \frac{AB \cdot BD \cdot \sin{(B + \pi/3})}{AC\cdot CD \cdot \sin{(C + \pi/3)}} = - \frac{AB \sin{(B + \pi/3)}}{AC\sin{(C + \pi/3)}}.$$

Write the other two similar ratios and multiply to get -1. The equality between the first and the last term remains valid for angles exceeding $2\pi/3$.

Comment: How yu have written that A'B /A'C = AREA ABD/ AREA ACD ...this means yu are taking A'B  and A'C  as hieght how ??

Comment: Triangles $ABD$ and $ACD$ have a common side $AD$. The ratio $A'B/A'C$ is the same as the ratio of the heights from $B$ and $C$.

Comment: To be clearer: the heights from $B$ and $C$ in the triangles $ABD$ and $ACD$, respectively; the perpendiculars from $B$ and $C$ to $AD$ are parallel.

Comment: @IMO2021GOLD The height from $A$ to the base $BC$ is common for the triangles $ABD$ and $ACD$. Compute the area of each triangle using this height, their corresponding base $BD$ and $DC$ using the formula height times base divided by $2$. When you divide the area of one by the other, the height cancels, the $2$ cancels and all that remains is the quotient of $BD$ and $DC$.

Comment: If $BB''$ is the height from $B$ in the triangle $ABD$ and $CC''$ is the height from $C$ in the triangle $ACD$, then the triangles $BA'B''$ and $CA'C''$ are similar and hence $A'B/A'C = BB''/CC''$.

Comment: $BA'$ is not necessarily perpendicular to $AD$; $BB''$ is constructed to be the perpendicular to $AD$ through $B$.